# Cant read url parameter with $location.search

Tags: angularjs

I only get an empty object using
`$location.search()`

having an url like:
`http://localhost/?test=baz`

so $location.search().test becomes undefined.

Why?

On
https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angularjs-query-string-handling-using-locationsearch
I can read

Note: `$location.search()` will cause the page to reload, i.e., the controller will reinitialize and run again from the beginning.

Is that true?

Comment: Put your live code.

Comment: Are you using html5Mode?

Comment: @charlietfl no, testing

Comment: I think the answer is 'Yes'. I'd had same problem before, so I solved this by using `event.preventDefault()` in `$locationChangeStart`. But I don't know why this behavior is occurred.

Comment: Oh, How about `$location.$$search.test` ?